# Links in Super User profile not showing up

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I've earned my "autobiographer" (cute! ;)) badge on Super User but when I go to my public profile the links that I've added *aren't* showing up. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Link or picture the two different pages please.

Comment: Most likely a browser add-on issue.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about disabling my recent uBlock browser extension in Chrome so I've done that for this site (and all StackExchange websites), as StackExchange ads are pretty unobtrusive (thank you!). Unfortunately, with a forced refresh of my profile, it didn't solve the problem. Do I need a certain reputation score for my links to be "clickable" (i.e., hyperlinks)? :)

Comment: @DougMehus Yes, you need 10 reputation points to get rid of [new user restrictions](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/new-user)

Answer (score 4):

Its by design. [Spammers ruin everything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/de-linkify-links-in-network-profile-if-a-network-wide-suspension-is-applied/238975#238975)

Comment: The post you linked is not related though, because this question is about _site profile_. Links in site profiles are rendered only for users with at least 10 reputation on the site, and it has been this way for years. The OP has 1 rep.

Comment: @CrazyIvan Have you even read the link? "As of November 13th 2017, all Website fields and links in the "About Me" profile sections are unlinked on stackexchange.com, **for all users regardless of their reputation on any site**. We can thank the increasing spam activity on the network "

Comment: @DavidPostill Have you even read the text you quoted? It is about stackexchange.com profiles, not site profiles. The question is about a SuperUser profile.